# ListPlot the results of FindMaximum

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to plot a list of the form whose elements are of the form

```
{value, {x -> value_x, y -> value_y}}
```

The list generated by FindMaximum applied on function with different initial positions. This means, that I have to transform the upper list to

```
{value_x, value_y, value}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListPointPlot3D[Join[#[[2,All,2]],{#[[1]]}]&/@yourList]
```

... or use `ListPlot3D` rather than the point plot. The command inside the `ListPointPlot3D` will extend to more dimensions and also works when your list contains say...

`{{43, {u->6,v->2,w->5}} <<more items>> }`

Answer (score 2):

```
s = {value, {x -> value_x, y -> value_y}}

{x /. s[[2]], y /. s[[2]], s[[1]]}
```

Comment: C'mon Jim, you have been a member for 8 months. You can at least format your code properly.

Comment: @Sektor.  Guilty as charged.  I will be more diligent in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
♭♭ = ## & @@@ {#2 & @@@ #2, #} & @@ # &;
```

Example:

```
lst ={{35.3919, {x -> 3.17532, y -> 0.826616}}, 
      {22.7658, {x -> 2.74215, y -> 1.86474}}, 
      {47.6532, {x -> 2.59448, y -> 5.939}}, 
      {51.3295, {x -> 2.25842, y -> 5.10077}}, 
      {26.2436, {x -> 1.23835, y -> 2.10218}},
      {36.0848, {x -> 1.85455, y -> 4.04917}}, 
      {52.9884, {x -> 2.7727,  y -> 4.73459}}, 
      {18.9687, {x -> 4.42552, y -> 3.75128}}}

lst2 = ♭♭ /@ lst
```

> {{3.17532, 0.826616, 35.3919},
>        {2.74215, 1.86474, 22.7658},
>        {2.59448, 5.939, 47.6532},
>        {2.25842, 5.10077, 51.3295},
>        {1.23835, 2.10218, 26.2436},
>        {1.85455, 4.04917, 36.0848},
>        {2.7727, 4.73459,  52.9884},
>        {4.42552, 3.75128, 18.9687}}

```
 BubbleChart3D[{##, 1} & @@@ lst2, BubbleSizes -> {.05, .05}, ChartStyle -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPointPlot3D[List /@ lst2, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, "ColorList"], 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[.05], BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]